# Remove a particular item from array based on condition and return other items in javascript

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an array with objects below

```
selectedOption = [
    {
            id: 'REPORTORDER',
            name: 'reportOrder'
        },
    {
            id: 'REORDER',
            name: ‘reorder'
        },
    {
            id: 'RETURNPRODUCTS',
            name: 'returnProducts'
        },
     {
            id: 'ENTERPO',
            name: 'enterPo'
        }
]
```

Based on a condition that if `shipmentStatus` is "CANCELLED" and `entriesList` is [] I want to remove the second item from the above array.

I have tried using filter method as written below:

```
selectedOption.filter(item => (shipmentStatus == "CANCELLED" && entriesList == []) ? item.name != "reorder" : item.name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `filter` returns a new array, so you'll need to reassign `selectedOption` to the result of `filter`.
2. The conditional will always fail since entriesList will never equal a new empty array. It's better to check if the array is empty by comparing the length to zero.
3. It's better to check the global conditions outside the filter.

```
if (shipmentStatus === 'CANCELLED' && Array.isArray(entriesList) && entriesList.length === 0) {
   selectedOption = selectedOption.filter(
     (item) => item.name != 'reorder'
   );
}
```

Comment: I was about to comment this same thing. You beat me to it. +1

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right you want to mutate array based on ***external*** condition, in that case, you must check condition *outside* `filter` like this

```js
let condition = true;
let selectedOption = [{
    id: 'REPORTORDER',
    name: 'reportOrder'
  },
  {
    id: 'REORDER',
    name: 'reorder'
  },
  {
    id: 'RETURNPRODUCTS',
    name: 'returnProducts'
  },
  {
    id: 'ENTERPO',
    name: 'enterPo'
  }
];
if (condition) selectedOption = selectedOption.filter(item => item.name != 'reorder')
console.log(selectedOption)
```

Comment: You can use outside conditions within filter. They get scoped to the lambda function if they are within the same code block.

Comment: yes you can, but what's the point of checking the same condition every time when you can check just once

Comment: You said that you MUST check it outside. I agree that you should check it once and do everything else inside, but it is nominal as far as performance and really just preference based.

Answer (score 0):

```
    const selectedOption = [
  {
    id: 'REPORTORDER',
    name: 'reportOrder',
  },
  {
    id: 'REORDER',
    name: 'reorder',
  },
  {
    id: 'RETURNPRODUCTS',
    name: 'returnProducts',
  },
  {
    id: 'ENTERPO',
    name: 'enterPo',
  }];

const shipmentStatus = 'cancelled';
const entriesList = [];

console.log(selectedOption.filter((x) => (x.name !== 'reorder') || !(shipmentStatus === 'cancelled' && !entriesList.length)));
```